# Android - Chronometer setBase() doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chronometer

I found that if I call `start()` right after `setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())` it will start counting from 00:00 (which is fine), see below:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.start();
    }
});
```

However, if I place the `setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())` out of the `setOnCLickListener()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    chronometer = findViewById(R.id.main_chronometer);
    startButton = findViewById(R.id.main_start_button);
    resetButton = findViewById(R.id.main_reset_button);

    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());    //no good here

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.start();
        }
    });
}
```

It will start counting from the elapsed time since this app launches. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe is caused by the asynchronous nature of user interaction. Your two examples can be broken down as follows:

## Calling [`setBase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer#setBase(long)) inside `onClick`

1. App launches
2. UI is configured; click listener is set on button
3. *Time passes...*
4. User clicks button
5. **Chronometer baseline is set to the current time**
6. **Chronometer is started**

Notice there is no time passing between steps 5 (chronometer baseline is set) and 6 (chronometer is started), which is why the chronometer correctly starts at 0 when you check its value.

## Calling `setBase` inside `onCreate` and outside `onClick`

1. App launches
2. UI is configured; click listener is set on button
3. **Chronometer baseline is set to the current time**
4. *Time passes...*
5. User clicks button
6. **Chronometer is started**

In this version, time passes between steps 3 (chronometer baseline is set) and 6 (chronometer is started), which is why the chronometer does not start at 0 when you check its value.

Comment: So, `setBase()` does two things, one is setting the base time, and two is setting 
 the start counting point to 0 (internally, also start counting internally), am I right?

Comment: Almost! The displayed time will always be a function of `<current time> - <base time>`. Therefore, when you set the base time you are resetting the counting point to 0 at exactly the same moment. As current time continues to increase, the counter will count up from 0.